# What is the basic setup on SVN to work on a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn

Lets say, I setup my svn host, like: http://www.example.com/svn

Then I create my project at a folder like: /home/me/workspace/my_app

I want to Setup my svn client and ignore files like tmp/* log/* db/schema.rb and such, so **what are the commands on console for that?** If possible can you write what the full sequence of commands to set this up?

*obs:* I have found no GUI that suit my needs on Ubuntu  <strike>kdesvn / rapidsvn</strike>  :(

Answer (score 0):

Using TortoiseSVN, you could simply use the ignore menu item, but I guess you're not using a GUI.

You can ignore single files by executing this *in the containing directory*:

```
svn propset svn:ignore filename .
```

Replace `filename` by the filename you want to ignore. This can also be a wildcard expression like `*.suo`. It can also be a directory like `tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

you can define the prop svn:ignore

so in your directory where you want ignore file made :

`svn propedit svn:ignore .`

An editor is open an add your information into. Close it and your file are ignore